# Cannot find external descriptions for DSPF in RPG IV

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have a server running IBM i 7.2 (no PTFs), which I am using to learn the system. I attempted to create a application with a single RPGLE source (CALCR) and a DSPF (CALCD) with a single record. However, when compiling the RPG code (via PDM) I get a error regarding the DSPF.

```
*RNF2120 40 a      000200  External descriptions for file CALCD not found; file is 
                           ignored.
```

The code is very simple as you can see below.

```
        *************** Beginning of data *********************************************
0001.00 H                                                                              
0002.00 FCALCD     CF   E             WORKSTN                                          
0003.00 C                   EVAL      *INLR = *ON                                      
        ****************** End of data ************************************************
```

The DSPF is "compiled" and exists in the same library as my RPG code. I also tested the same code on PUB400 and encountered no error. I'm thinking there is something wrong with the stock configuration of my IBM I installation.

Comment: So I changed my current lib (CHGCURLIB) to the library that I was working in PDU, and it compiled! However, I'm not sure why I need to change my current library to compile code. Should the compiler check the library that the code is in automatically for other files (e.g. DSPF)?

Comment: no, the library list is used to find the objects, unless you qualify them with extname() 
 & extfile()...

Comment: If you don't want to have your library in your library list, you can hard-code the library name, both for compile-time EXTDESC('MYLIB/DSPF') and for run-time EXTFILE('MYLIB/DSPF') (or EXTFILE(*EXTDESC) if you also coded the EXTDESC keyword). 

If you have externally-described data structures that you want the compiler to find without the file being in your library list, you can hard-code the library with EXTNAME('MYLIB/MYFILE').

Answer (score 2):

First, check your library list. But, if that is correct, you need at least some base PTF's. If there is a bug somewhere, it is fixed in those PTF's. Without those, anything you try that is wonkey, no one can help you. Even at the first GA date, IBM shipped some PTF's to fix issues found during beta stages.

If you can't get PTF's, then it is best to just try using pub400.